# Wordpress Pages Vs. Categories

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme that is placing my pages and catagories in the opposite places I want them (See Below). Is there a way I can pragmatically switch the places where the pages (about, contact, apps) with the categories? I've looked around but cant find anyone who has had a similar issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the theme supports changing menu items, then @golddc's answer tells you what to do.  But if the theme doesn't support it and you're not ready to develop a theme from scratch, you may be able to modify the existing theme:

1. Go into the Wordpress back-end and navigate to Appearance > Editor (two options below Appearance > Menu).
2. Find the file on the right that governs the site's header.  This is probably header.php.  The right file will hopefully include `wp_list_pages();` and `wp_list_categories();` somewhere, since these are the functions which, predictably enough, tell Wordpress to list the site's pages and categories, respectively.
3. Switch the locations of `wp_list_pages();` and `wp_list_categories();` and see if that has the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "Menu" settings in the WP backend, which you can find at Appearance -> Menus. If the theme supports it, you can create menu items with categories.

Check here for how to use the menus:

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

If the theme doesn't support that (although I think Menus is supported) and it's definitely needed, you may have to consider developing your own theme.